# for loop with shutil.copytree wrongly copying ALL files for EVERY single folder

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, shutil

In this for loop it is copying ALL the folders for every sub-folder. so its taking crazily long and not what i want. So for e.g. for for folder “SPRING2158” it is copying everything starting from “SPRING00001” to the end “SPRING09999”. But it only should copy for images starting with “SPRING2158”. Not for everything.

```
import os
import shutil 

path = os.path.expanduser('/content/images/FemaleImages')   
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
  if file_name[:10] in nameTrainF:
    shutil.copytree(path+'/', '/content/OutTrainF/'+file_name[:10]+'/')   
  if file_name[:10] in nameValF:
    shutil.copytree(path+'/', '/content/OutValF/'+file_name[:10]+'/')   
  if file_name[:10] in nameTestF:
    shutil.copytree(path+'/', '/content/OutTestF/'+file_name[:10]+'/')
```

To give you an idea of the data structure, below is how the data looks like when extracting it, when extracting from RAR format.

```
 !unrar e "/content/drive/My Drive/femaleset.rar" "/content/images/FemaleImages/" 

Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4796-D7-V40-H50.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4796-D7-V40-H60.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4796-D7-V40-H70.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4796-D7-V40-H80.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4796-D7-V40-H90.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H0.png      OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H10.png     OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H100.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H110.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H120.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H130.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H140.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H150.png    OK 
Extracting  /content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING4798-D7-V0-H160.png    OK
```

screenshot of output folder in Colab

[image: screenshot of output folder in Colab]

Added the updated code below for additional question from the comments:

```
path = os.path.expanduser('/content/images/FemaleImages')  
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
  if file_name[:10] in nameTrainF:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutTrainF/', file_name[:10],'/'))   
  if file_name[:10] in nameValF:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutValF/', file_name[:10],'/')) 
  if file_name[:10] in nameTestF:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutTestF/', file_name[:10],'/'))
```

Comment: please add the rest of the code. and I don't see any subfolders in your directory structure

Comment: sorry there are no sub-folders in code.  It was a term I was just using to describe the situation. But I added a screenshot of the example output of the files. Please let me know if i can provide anything else, thanks!

Comment: so you basically want to group the images based on their prefix? If that's the case, [use the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/sort-files-into-directories-named-by-prefix-of-file)

Comment: The source directory `path+'/'` is the entire tree, not the current directory of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not copying just the current file of the iteration, you're copying everything in `path` each time. Use `shutil.copy2()` to copy a file, not `shutil.copytree()`.

Also, you should use `os.path.join()` to combine directories and filenames, rather than concatenation.

```
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
  prefix = name[:10]
  if prefix in nameTrainF:
    target = os.path.join('/content/OutTrainF/', prefix, '')
    os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), target)   
  if prefix in nameValF:
    target = os.path.join('/content/OutValF/', prefix, '')
    os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), target)   
  if prefix in nameTestF:
    target = os.path.join('/content/OutTestF/', prefix, '')
    os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), target)
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar ! However when i use your code , it gives error thats its not a directory as shown below.  
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/images/FemaleImages/SPRING2158-D7-V30-H310.png'

Comment: Why are you using `copytree()` if it's not a directory?

Comment: Use `shutil.copy2()` to copy a file.

Comment: The code was processing and no errors. However , there is no output at all for some reasons... 

`for file_name in os.listdir(path):
  if file_name[:10] in nameTrainF:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutTrainF/', file_name[:10],'/'))   
  if file_name[:10] in nameValF:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutValF/', file_name[:10],'/')) 
  if file_name[:10] in nameTestF:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutTestF/', file_name[:10],'/'))   `

Comment: Try the updated code that adds an empty string to the end of the `os.path.join()` call, so it will create a directory path.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/OutTrainF/SPRING2158/'

Comment: You need to create the target directory if it doesn't exist. `shutil.copy2()` won't create it automatically.

Comment: Sorry, can you please help, why do i get this error. Thanks so much. 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 

'/content/OutTrainF/SPRING2158'
if file_name[:10] in nameTrainF:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join('/content/OutTrainF/',file_name[:10]))
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, file_name), os.path.join('/content/OutTrainF/', file_name[:10], ''))

Comment: I added the code to create the directories.

Comment: thank you Barmar!!!! its all good now  :)

Comment: the code works, thx, but can i please ask another question. The current output are stored in path: 
/content/OutTrainF/SPRING0239/SPRING0239-D7-V10-H290.png
So it creates a folder /SPRING0239/ which contains the 150 images that begin with SPRING0239. How can I make the output directly without the folders?
so desired output is:
/content/OutTrainF/SPRING0239-D7-V10-H290.png
Thank you

Comment: Just set `target` to that desired directory.